# VBA. Deleting multiple cells in a row if one cell is blank

Tags: excel, vba, delete-row

I have multiple columns in an excel sheet...say `A1:D10`.
I want to find any blank cells in column C, delete that cell as well as the A,B, and D cells of that same row, then shift up.  But only in the range of `A1:D10`.  I have other information in this excel sheet outside this range that I want to perserve in its original position.  Therefore I can not use somthing like this:

```
.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
```

Nor can I get something like the following to work, because it only shifts the single column up, not all four columns.

```
Set rng = Range("A1:D10").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
rng.Rows.Delete Shift:=xlShiftUp
```

Comment: When you say _I have other information in this excel sheet outside this range that I want to perserve in its original position_ do you have data in Columns A to D _below_ row 10 that you want to stay where it is?

Answer (score 0):

If there is *no* data in columns `A` to `D` below row 10 that you don't want to move up, then `SpecialCells` and `Delete Shift Up` can be used like this

```
Sub Demo1()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim TestColumn As Long
    Dim StartColumn As Long
    Dim EndColumn As Long
    Dim FirstRow As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long

    Dim i As Long
    Dim rng As Range, arr As Range

    ' set up reference data
    Set ws = ActiveSheet '<~~ update as required
    TestColumn = 3  'C
    StartColumn = 1 'A
    EndColumn = 4   'D
    FirstRow = 1
    LastRow = 10

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    With ws
        On Error Resume Next
            Set rng = .Range(.Cells(FirstRow, TestColumn), .Cells(LastRow, TestColumn)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
        On Error GoTo 0

        If Not rng Is Nothing Then
            For Each arr In rng.Areas
                arr.EntireRow.Resize(, EndColumn - StartColumn + 1).Delete Shift:=xlShiftUp
            Next
        End If
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

If there *is*  data in columns `A` to `D` below row 10 that you don't want to move up, then you can use `Cut` and `Paste`, like this

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim TestColumn As Long
    Dim StartColumn As Long
    Dim EndColumn As Long
    Dim FirstRow As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long

    Dim i As Long

    ' set up reference data
    Set ws = ActiveSheet '<~~ update as required
    TestColumn = 3  'C
    StartColumn = 1 'A
    EndColumn = 4   'D
    FirstRow = 1
    LastRow = 10

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    With ws
        If IsEmpty(.Cells(LastRow, TestColumn)) Then
            .Cells(LastRow, StartColumn).Resize(1, EndColumn - StartColumn + 1).Clear
        End If
        For i = LastRow - 1 To FirstRow Step -1
            If IsEmpty(.Cells(i, TestColumn)) Then
                .Range(.Cells(i + 1, StartColumn), .Cells(LastRow, EndColumn)).Cut .Cells(i, StartColumn)
            End If
        Next
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Comment: Great.. I was thinking about cut paste.. But from top to bottom and then it would have gone wrong if there are two consecutive blank cells in c1:c10

Comment: @Naresh, yep, looping bottom up, and dealing with row 10 seperately are the key points.  Also, [FYI](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Using Variant Array Method

```
Sub test2()
    Dim rngDB As Range, vDB As Variant
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, n As Integer
    Dim k As Integer

    Set rngDB = Range("a1:d10")

    vDB = rngDB

    n = UBound(vDB, 1)
    For i = 1 To n
        If IsEmpty(vDB(i, 3)) Then
            For j = 1 To 4
                If j <> 3 Then
                    vDB(i, j) = Empty
                End If
            Next j
        End If
    Next i
    For j = 1 To 4
        If j <> 3 Then
            For i = 1 To n - 1
                For k = i To n - 1
                    If vDB(k, j) = Empty Then
                        vDB(k, j) = vDB(k + 1, j)
                        vDB(k + 1, j) = Empty
                    End If
                Next k
            Next i
        End If
    Next j
    rngDB = vDB
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

The below will take care of your requirement by looking for an empty cell in column 3, and deleting the row and shifting up only in that row.

```
Sub deleteEmptyRow()
Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To 10
        If Cells(i, 3) = "" Then
            Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 4)).delete Shift:=xlUp
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: This works great, thanks.  I forgot you can reference cells this way in VBA.  Makes everything easier.